# Single-Threaded enumeration works, but Multi-Threaded does not, not sure why

Tags: c#, multithreading, foreach, nested, enumeration

Some more details:
I have a list of arrays of circle objects. Each circle has a list area that corresponds to a pixel on a bitmap.
When I call diffCircles, I'm comparing the vector2's in each area of each circle in each array iteratively to remove their area from the original circle.

I'm trying to add multithreading to a project of mine (to process a lot of short operations in a small span of time).

The original method is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < generations.Count-1; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < generations[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    foreach (Circle circle in generations[i][j].children)
                    {
                        Circle.DiffCircles(generations[0][0], circle);
                    }
                }
            }
```

And with the above implementation, the program works perfectly as intended (it's just slow).

However if I try to change it to:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < generations.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < generations[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    foreach (Circle circle in generations[i][j].children)
                    {
                        Thread diffCirc = new Thread(() => Circle.DiffCircles(generations[0][0], circle));
                        diffCirc.Start();
                    }
                }
            }
```

The program stops working as intended.

The DiffCircles method is

```
public static void DiffCircles(Circle original, Circle toSubtract)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < original.area.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j > toSubtract.area.Count - 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (original.area[i-1].X == toSubtract.area[j-1].X
                            && original.area[i-1].Y == toSubtract.area[j-1].Y)
                        {
                            original.area.Remove(original.area[i-1]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Could I get any advice? I've never worked with multi-threading before. I can't understand why the multithreaded implementation doesn't work, but the singlethreaded implementation does. Would appreciate any advice!

Comment: You cant use multi threading for this, main reason being you want to remove parts of the original circle. So if it works by some miracle you would have a race condition (unless you tell me its not important how its removed first ). And then if it doesnt matter how its done maybe you should think how to split the problem in individually separated pieces and then join them

Comment: By the time the circles areas are removed from the main circle, all the circles have been generated, and since the diffCircles method only removes matching areas (if the two vectors' components are equal) I don't *think* it should matter in which order they are removed.

Comment: This doesn't look like a good strategy to me. You're spinning up a new thread for every operation, and threads come with a cost. So, even if you make it work, it won't necessarily solve your problem - in fact, it may end up being even slower. 
P.S. "The program stops working as intended" - when saying that something doesn't work the way you expected it to, you should also describe what you mean by that (what actually happens). E.g. Is it producing wrong results? Does it crash? Does it block? Does it just exit as soon as you run it?

Comment: "I don't think it should matter in which order they are removed" - it's not the ordering that's the problem. Your DiffCircles operation is not *atomic* ("indivisible"); execution flow jumps around from one thread to another, and it can happen at any point in your code, before each individual diff operation has finished. Or it happens in parallel if on multiple cores. If Circle is a reference type, they will all be working on the same object, and possibly leave it in an inconsistent state.

Comment: You could take a look at the [`Parallel.For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for) method. It uses threads form the `ThreadPool`, instead of spawning a new thread for every piece of processing.

Comment: When I meant program stops working as intended, the resultant bitmap showed a complete circle (unaltered) as a result, rather than a circle with *any* pixels missing. Normally, the resultant circle on the bitmap has a significant quantity of missing area (the program randomizes some of it).

I'll look at some of the other suggestions, thanks!

Comment: You have started a lot of Threads, but I don't see that you ever wait for their completion. After cycle is finished it may be that none of your threads will ever do anything. Just for test - add Thread.Sleep(2000) afrer cycle and see if any change was made

Answer (score 0):

Maybe deadlock caused by thread contention.

You can try to lock your thread.

```
lock(new object()){
    Thread diffCirc = new Thread(() => Circle.DiffCircles(generations[0][0], circle));
    diffCirc.Start();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix it :(